# How to compile assembly file containing offload to mic

Tags: assembly, intel, intel-mic

I write a C file named "test.c", which contains offload operation on mic. Then I compile it to assembly file using the command "icc -S test.c". This produced two assembly files named "test.s" and "testMIC.s". When I continue to compile them to executable file, there are errors as follows.

1. use commad "icc test.s"

   /tmp/iccG8ZTVA.o: In function `main':
   test.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to`__kmpc_begin'
   test.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `__offload_target_acquire'
   test.c:(.text+0x11f): undefined reference to`__offload_offload'
   test.c:(.text+0x15b): undefined reference to `__kmpc_end'
2. use commad "icc testMIC.s"

   /tmp/icc7qv8qX.o: In function `__offload_entry_test_c_10main':
   test.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to`__intel_new_proc_init_R'
   test.c:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `__offload_target_enter'
   test.c:(.text+0x111): undefined reference to`__offload_target_leave'
   /tmp/icc7qv8qX.o: In function `main':
   test.c:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to`__intel_new_proc_init_R'
3. use commad "icc test.s testMIC.s"

   /tmp/iccEOtVAs.o: In function `foo':
   test.c:(.text+0x170): multiple definition of`foo'
   /tmp/icczmGFBD.o:test.c:(.text+0x170): first defined here
   /tmp/iccEOtVAs.o: In function `main':
   test.c:(.text+0x128): multiple definition of`main'
   /tmp/icczmGFBD.o:test.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
   /tmp/icczmGFBD.o: In function `main':
   test.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to`__kmpc_begin'
   test.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `__offload_target_acquire'
   test.c:(.text+0x11f): undefined reference to`__offload_offload'
   test.c:(.text+0x15b): undefined reference to `__kmpc_end'
   /tmp/iccEOtVAs.o: In function`__offload_entry_test_c_10main':
   test.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `__intel_new_proc_init_R'
   test.c:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to`__offload_target_enter'
   test.c:(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `__offload_target_leave'
   /tmp/iccEOtVAs.o: In function`main':
   test.c:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `__intel_new_proc_init_R'

Is there any one can help me solve this problem?

the test.c:

```
__attribute__((target(mic)))
int foo(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}

int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    int a=1, b=2;
    #pragma offload target (mic)
    {
        c = foo(a, b);
    }
    printf("c: %d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An assemblyfile is not compiled it is assembled. So you have to invoke the assembler instead of the compiler.

Comment: You need include libraries you're using for the linker.

Comment: Try to add -openmp option:  icc -openmp test.s

Answer (score 0):

After generating two assembly files test.s and testMIC.s using the command

% icc -S test.c

You should be able to generate the executable a.out with the following command

% icc test.s

The compiler detects that test.s has offload code, so it searches for testMIC.s and link them to generate the executable a.out that you can run from host.

However, it is not correct to issue "icc testMIC.s" nor "icc test.s testMIC.s"